# prettyphoto not displaying thumbnail but resolves image when clicked

Tags: javascript, wordpress, prettyphoto

I had to move my wordpress site to a different directory folder on my hosting server. Now for some reason on the portfolio pages of my website it's not displaying the thumbnail preview for lightbox images. The image will display when the thumbnail is clicked so I know it's pulling the right image from the right place but why is it not showing the preview thumbnail?

Here is a link:

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The src is empty on the thumbnails

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where would I change this? It was working before I moved the site and I added the pictures the same way as I did before.

Comment: Paste up the code from the template that's being used for that page.  It's not even the wrong url or directory that's being applied, there is nothing at all in the img src . We just need to see the section of the template inside the loop that produces the <a class="image-wrap" .... </a>

Comment: Here is the code from the portfolio page. Not sure if this is what your looking for.. please forgive my ignorance :(

Comment: <span class="image-border"><a class="image-wrap" href="<?php echo $img_url;?>" rel="<?php echo $prettyType; ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /><span class="zoom-icon"></span></a></span>

Comment: OK, so where are $img_url and $image set and what is the code for that? The former is OK, it's the $image variable which has not been set.

Comment: $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full'); //get img URL
    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 220, 147, true ); //resize & crop img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well based on your comments the switch across from one server to another has stopped the method aq_resize() working.  It is called Aqua-Resizer, here's the Github page;

https://github.com/sy4mil/Aqua-Resizer/blob/master/aq_resizer.php

The [wiki](https://github.com/sy4mil/Aqua-Resizer/wiki) on it explains it's use but if all you've done is change the server then you will have to look at other explanations for why it's not working.  The following is a list you can start looking through;

Make sure your functions.php still has `require_once('aq_resizer.php');` with the correct path to this script.  Make sure the script is actually there. If it is try changing the file permissions on the file to see if that helps.  If the script uses a cache directory try changing the permissions on this.

It could also be that the PHP version on the new server is different (maybe, I'm guessing now)?  Check that too.

Comment: //Aqua Resizer for image cropping and resizing on the fly
 require_once $includes_path . 'aq_resizer.php';

Comment: $includes_path = TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/';

Comment: AHHHHHHH. Finally. I took the github code and replaced it with my existing code which looked like it was an earlier version and BAM it WORKS! I don't know why it worked before I moved my site and suddenly didn't but I don't care anymore lol. McNab, you're the man! You have no idea how much I appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the img src defined which PrettyPhoto uses to pull the thumb:

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but where do I define the img src? In the prettyphoto js? The theme is setup so I add portfolio pics like I'm making a post and use the image I want as the featured image in the post and it would worked great before I moved my site.

Comment: I'm glad McNab got it figured out. I was thinking it was a possible PHP-GD/extensions issue (older version of PHP maybe on your old server) between the two hosts and maybe the newer script resolved that in the new host environment.

Comment: Btw, did you test creating a new page and ensuring your "uploads" folder is working properly? I've seen issues like that after a move where I needed to drop into a shell account and change the permissions on the folder. You can also do it through file manager in cPanel or FTP.